# Debezium SQL Server Source Connector set Kafka broker

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, debezium, confluent-platform

I'm trying to setup docker environment of Confluent Kafka Platform and integrate with Debezium SQL Server Source Connector.

I followed [this](https://docs.confluent.io/current/quickstart/ce-docker-quickstart.html) Confluent's guide for the Kafka platform, then [this](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/debezium-connect-sqlserver/index.html) Debezium tutorial for the SQL Server Source Connector.

My broker container is named `broker`, this container and the rest of the other containers (indclue `connect` container) are in the same network, and I made sure they can ping&telnet each other.

In Debezium tutorial, I stuck in the step of [Start The Debezium SQL Server Connector](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/debezium-connect-sqlserver/index.html#start-the-debezium-sql-server-connector) because I'm receiving an error which indicates that the connector is trying to access Kafka broker through `localhost:9092` instead of `broker:9092`:

```
[2020-03-29 10:46:30,907] WARN [Consumer clientId=server1-dbhistory, groupId=server1-dbhistory] Connection to node 1 (localhost/127.0.0.1:9092) could not be established. Broker may not be available. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
[2020-03-29 10:46:32,114] WARN [Consumer clientId=server1-dbhistory, groupId=server1-dbhistory] Connection to node 1 (localhost/127.0.0.1:9092) could not be established. Broker may not be available. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
[2020-03-29 10:46:32,969] WARN [Consumer clientId=server1-dbhistory, groupId=server1-dbhistory] Connection to node 1 (localhost/127.0.0.1:9092) could not be established. Broker may not be available. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
[2020-03-29 10:46:34,127] WARN [Consumer clientId=server1-dbhistory, groupId=server1-dbhistory] Connection to node 1 (localhost/127.0.0.1:9092) could not be established. Broker may not be available. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
[2020-03-29 10:46:35,333] WARN [Consumer clientId=server1-dbhistory, groupId=server1-dbhistory] Connection to node 1 (localhost/127.0.0.1:9092) could not be established. Broker may not be available. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
[2020-03-29 10:46:36,238] WARN [Consumer clientId=server1-dbhistory, groupId=server1-dbhistory] Connection to node 1 (localhost/127.0.0.1:9092) could not be established. Broker may not be available. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
```

Until it finally timeouts:

```
[2020-03-29 10:46:38,664] ERROR WorkerSourceTask{id=inventory-connector-0} Task threw an uncaught and unrecoverable exception (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask)
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Failed to get offsets by times in 60000ms
```

The funny thing is that I can see that my configuration is received successfully at the start of the log (look for the `broker:9092`):

```
[2020-03-29 10:45:38,618] INFO    database.history.kafka.bootstrap.servers = broker:9092 (io.debezium.connector.common.BaseSourceTask)
```

...

```
[2020-03-29 10:45:38,655] INFO ConsumerConfig values:
        allow.auto.create.topics = true
        auto.commit.interval.ms = 5000
        auto.offset.reset = earliest
        bootstrap.servers = [broker:9092]
        check.crcs = true
        client.dns.lookup = default
        client.id = server1-dbhistory
        client.rack =
        connections.max.idle.ms = 540000
        default.api.timeout.ms = 60000
        enable.auto.commit = false
        exclude.internal.topics = true
        fetch.max.bytes = 52428800
        fetch.max.wait.ms = 500
        fetch.min.bytes = 1
        group.id = server1-dbhistory
        group.instance.id = null
```

This is my configuration file: `register-sqlserver.json`:

```
{
 "name": "inventory-connector",
 "config": {
     "connector.class" : "io.debezium.connector.sqlserver.SqlServerConnector",
     "tasks.max" : "1",
     "database.server.name" : "server1",
     "database.hostname" : "sqlserver_1",
     "database.port" : "1433",
     "database.user" : "sa",
     "database.password" : "Password!",
     "database.dbname" : "testDB",
     "database.history.kafka.bootstrap.servers" : "broker:9092",
     "database.history.kafka.topic": "schema-changes.inventory"
     }
 }
```

I add the connector via the host machine as follows (just like the guide):

```
curl -i -X POST -H "Accept:application/json" -H "Content-Type:application/json" http://localhost:8083/connectors/ -d @register-sqlserver.json
```

The logs that I've shown are the output of `connect` container logs.

No other `localhost` words are presented in my full logs, so no worries about other configurations with default value `localhost` that I could've been missed as a lead.

Will appreciate any help :)

Comment: Each Docker container is its own little Linux instance, so `localhost` and `127.0.0.1` point to itself. If you run `docker network inspect` it should list each running container with its own "IPv4Address" entry, often in the 172.17.0.0/16 network. Use the IP address listed against your target instance (broker).

Comment: Hey @AlwaysLearning ,I understand that it should not be `localhost` or `127.0.0.1`, this is why I used the `broker` DNS which automatically works if the containers are at the same docker network, anyway I tried to use the broker's ip addres as you suggested (in my case it was `172.21.0.3`); now I am getting the exact same problem- it tries to reach `localhost` while logging my configuration as `bootstrap.servers =[172.21.0.3:9092]`. Any idea why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is down to *advertised listeners*.

You're connecting to the broker on `9092` which per [the config](https://github.com/confluentinc/examples/blob/5.4.1-post/cp-all-in-one/docker-compose.yml#L26) is for the listener which advertises its host as `localhost`

```
KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://broker:29092,PLAINTEXT_HOST://localhost:9092
```

That means that the client (Debezium, in this case) will initially connect to the bootstrap server that you give it (`broker:9092`) but the broker will hand back to the client the advertised host (`localhost`) - and the client will then try to connect to that. Since they're on separate instances, `localhost` for the Debeziu, connector is not the broker, and the connection fails.

Ref: https://rmoff.net/2018/08/02/kafka-listeners-explained/

**Solution:**

Use port `29092`, which per the above config is bound to the `broker` advertised host, which *will* resolve correctly from the Debezium container

```
"database.history.kafka.bootstrap.servers" : "broker:29092"
```